# MongoDB two same records

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm doing a project which is backed by Nodejs and MongoDB. I am quite new to MongoDB and I am lacking a clue why I quite often(almost always) get two same records in collections when I do posts. The two records only differ by ID, which are for example `ObjectId("53aefb0fc68a0810504d2066")` and `53aefb0fc68a0810504d2066`, is this normal or am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any pointers.

Here is some node code:

server.js:

```
app.post("/:collection", function (req, res) {
    var object = req.body;
    var collection = req.params.collection;

    collectionDriver.save(collection, object, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(400, [err, object]);
        } else {
            res.send(201, docs);
        }
    });
});
```

collectionDriver:

```
save: function(collectionName, obj, callback) {
    this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
        if( error ) callback(error);
            else {
                obj.created_at = new Date();
                the_collection.insert(obj, function() {
                    callback(null, obj);
            });
        }
    });
},

getCollection: function(collectionName, callback) {
    this.db.collection(collectionName, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: No, it's not normal. But we need to see your code to be able to help you.

Comment: code posted, hope helps. I cant post everything here since they are a bit longer.

Comment: You are posting and looking in the wrong place. Open a mongo shell and try this `db.test.insert({ name: "Bill"})` then do that again. Same name, different `_id`. This is because "name" is not a "primary key" (`_id` always) and does not have a "unique" index. So bottom line is you are doing something wrong, but you are not pointing anyone to the **right** place to see that.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, Thanks for respond. I have no idea which part is going wrong right now. So I don't know where to point. I am probably gonna delete this question because this is not clear. thanks again.

Comment: Is it possible that the client is sending the data twice?

Comment: Best advice to give is find where something like that is happening. If that is not then clear then post the code around that.

Comment: could be from client side. I will figure that out. thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you ask MongoDB to `save` an object without an `_id` field, it automatically generates a new, globally unique ObjectID for that field and saves the object under that ObjectID.

When you want to use `save` to update an existing document, you need to make sure that the `_id` field is populated with the `_id` of the document you want to update.

Alternatively, you can create an [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/#index-type-unique) on those fields you consider relevant for determining what's a duplicate and what isn't. However, in that case an attempt to save an already existing document will throw an error instead of replacing the document.